# Inter frame SOP - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

In a Chrome Extension, I'm trying to get gmail compose body content.

An error jumps out sporadically, and does not prevents it from working.

This is being run as a content script. I believe permissions are not the issue here, because when there is a permission missing, the error is different and the operation is **blocked** by Chrome, definitely not the case.

Error comes out in this line:

```
encodeURIComponent($canvas.find('iframe').contents().find('body').text());
```

where

```
var $canvas = $('#canvas_frame').contents();
```

Any information on this error and a possible turnaround?[image]

Comment: You can't access the contents of an iframe from one origin (`https://apis.google.com`) using JavaScript from another origin (`https://mail.google.com`). I'm not sure if there is a good fix.

Comment: Maybe permissions on manifest.json?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482989/allowing-access-to-cross-domain-frame-in-application.  While cross-domain Ajax is possible, it seems cross-domain iframe access is not.

Comment: It works 90% of the time, maybe more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not read cross site content using javascript. XSS Auditor of Google Chorme will never allow this.

Please have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

#### UPDATE 1 -

There is support for cross site communication using window.postMessage() in Chrome 2+. Please have a look at this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: Have a look at Cross-Origin Communication with window.postMessage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: I haven't use windows.postmessage in Chrome. This is not answering the question...

Answer (score 2):

To give a good answer, we need more information:

- where exactly you are running this code, is it in the web page, the extension's content script or the etension's background script?
- Also, what does your manifest.json file look like?  Which sites have you asked for permission to run on.

I suspect this is a case of a badly-written error message and really it is saying: your extension does not have permission to run on apis.google.com.  In that case, simply add permissions for apis.google.com.  More details are in the Chrome extensions docs: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions

Comment: Updated the information, I want to know specifically why this error is generated, permissions give a different error and block the operation, not the case here...