# Do Background pages have access to shared DOM?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

If So, how to access them?

I'm talking about a Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But with message passing (postMessage), you pages can communicate with the background page.

Comment: I have a problem with [SOP privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11852899/1341526). I thought about using background pages to have more privileges...

Comment: Not sure where SOP privileges comes into this, see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html . In general, if you want to avoid SOP issues you need to make a packaged app with the proper permissions in the manifest file, but this is unrelated to "intra-page" communication in extensions AFAIK.

Comment: I've read about the message passing, but I really need a SOP passing technic for intra frame operation...

Comment: AFAIK, those are hacks and can't be trusted, but my knowledge about that is limited.